# yii2 after log out redirect to respective homepage according to dns url

Tags: yii2

I have an application that has a homepage for one dns (mypijamas.website.com) which is linked to the siteController and a different home page for the ones who access the site by (summer.website.com) which is linked to the summerSiteController and the log in system goes to the backend and is the same for both homepages. My question is, if a person that come from the second dns and logout is in the siteController it redirect to the homepage of the first dns and I want to redirect him to the second dns homepage. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would probably use cookies. Set them on page visit, and on logout via condition, based on cookies value, redirect accordingly. But there might be better solution I am not aware of right now.